# Finding unique values of a node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database with several nodes each having many properties. I am trying to find a list of unique values available for each property.

Currently, I can search for nodes that have a certain value 'xxx' with a query in this manner below however, I want to find all the unique values 'xxx','yyy', etc. that may exist in all the nodes in my database.

```
match (n:Db_Nodes) where n.stringProperty = "xxx" return n
```

How should I go about structuring the query desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` Clause to return all the unique values for this property.

**There are two ways to get all the values:**

Get all the values in a list. Here result will be one single record with all the unique values in the form of a list.

```
MATCH (n:Db_Nodes) RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n.stringProperty) as propertyList
```

Get one value per record. Here multiple records will be returned(One per unique property value).

```
MATCH (n:Db_Nodes) RETURN DISTINCT n.stringProperty
```